# Wordpress e-commerce retail platform

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a university retail platform that connects sellers with consumers. What is the best premium template and plugin to use, also are there free template and plugin I can use?

Answer (score 0):

The Shopify plug in is extremely simple to use & I highly recommend it if you don't have any extensive end-to-end dev experience & would prefer to stay away from code. 
However if you want a little more flexibility & control over your shop, I personally have used WooCommerce & it's additional plugin add-ons which are relatively simple to use as well. Outside of those two, the printful plugin does a great job of facilitating your store if you have no inventory already ready to go.